# Selecting most relevant word from lists of candidate words

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Let's suppose I have 1000's of training examples where each consists of a bucket e.g. `'engineering'` or `'management'` and a list of tags e.g. `['software', 'python', 'product']` where a human has selected the most relevant tag for the use case e.g.`'software'`.

So our data is like:

```
bucket         tags                        best_tag
engineering    [fullstack, software]       software
engineering    [java, python, software]    software
management     [technical, product]        product
```

What kind of model or approach would suit taking a list of tags and predicting the best tag based on some kind of underlying latent hierarchy?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is such a dataset publicly accessible? It seems like a fun project to work on!

Comment: @ValentinCalomme Unfortunately the data isn't publicly available just yet, but may be possible in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could approach this problem

- **Word embeddings**

If you have word embeddings at hand, you can look at the distance between the tags and the bucket and pick the one with the smallest distance.

- **Frequentist approach**

You could simply look at the frequency of a bucket/tag pair and choose this. Likely not the best model, but might already go a long way.

- **Recommender system**

Given a bucket, your goal is to recommend the best tag. You can use collaborative filtering or neural approaches to train a recommender. I feel this could work well especially if the data is sparse (i.e. lots of different tags, lots of buckets).

The caveat I would see with this approach is that you would technically always compare all tags, which only works if tag A is always better than tag B regardless of which tags are proposed to the user.

- **Ranking problem**

You could look at it as a ranking problem, I recommend reading [this blog](https://medium.com/@nikhilbd/intuitive-explanation-of-learning-to-rank-and-ranknet-lambdarank-and-lambdamart-fe1e17fac418) to have a better idea of how you can train such model.

- **Classification problem**

This becomes a classification problem if you turn your problem into the following: given a bucket, and two tags (A & B), return 0 if tag A is preferred, 1 if tag B is preferred. You can create your training data as every combination of two tags from your data, times 2 (swap A and B).

The caveat is that given N tags, you might need to do a round-robin or tournament approach to know which tag is the winner, due to the pairwise nature.

- **Recurrent/Convolutional network**

If you want to implicitly deal with the variable-length nature of the problem, you could pass your tags as a sequence. Since your tags have no particular order, this creates a different input for each permutation of the tags. During training, this provides more data points, and during inference, this could be used to create an ensemble (i.e. predict a tag for each permutation and do majority voting).

If you believe that it matters in which order the tags are presented to the user, then deal with the sequence in the order it is in your data.

Your LSTM/CNN would essentially learn to output a single score for each item, such that the item with the highest score is the desired one.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer, much appreciated! I have just been reading the blog post on ranking and that seems to be great use case and will definitely explore further. I also like the classification approach as it seems a lot more intuitive and explainable. I suppose that in either case it would be important to train a separate model for each bucket?

Comment: Depending on how many buckets you have, you could do that. Otherwise, train a single model, and add the bucket as part of the input, which should condition your model. The latter is preferred in my opinion